# scipy.integrate.quad on arrays of limits

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, integral

quad from scipy.integrate needs the arguments func, a, b. Where func is a function to integrate and a and b is the lower and upper integration limits, respectively. a and b has to be numbers.

I have a situation where I need to evaluate the integral of a function for hundreds of thousands of different a, b and sum the results. This takes a long time to loop through. I tried to just give quad arrays for a and b, hoping quad would return the corresponding array, but that didn't work.

Here is a code illustrating what I'm trying to do, with both the Python loop that works, but is very slow, and my attempt at vectorizing that doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to this problem can be solved in a fast (numpy-is) way?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

# The function I need to integrate:
def f(x):
    return np.exp(-x*x)

# The large lists of different limits:
a_list = np.linspace(1, 100, 1e5)
b_list = np.linspace(2, 200, 1e5)

# Slow loop:
total_slow = 0  # Sum of all the integrals.
for a, b in zip(a_list, b_list):
    total_slow += quad(f, a, b)[0]
        # (quad returns a tuple where the first index is the result,
        # therefore the [0])

# Vectorized approach (which doesn't work):
total_fast = np.sum(quad(f, a_list, b_list)[0])

"""This error is returned:

 line 329, in _quad
    if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than 
one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
"""
```

**EDIT:**

The actual function I need to integrate (`rho`) also contains two other factors. `rho0` is an array with the same length as `a_list` and `b_list`. `H` is a scalar.

```
def rho(x, rho0, H):
    return rho0 * np.exp(- x*x / (2*H*H))
```

**EDIT2:**

Profiling of different solutions. ´space_sylinder` is the function where the integral happens. Warren Weckesser suggestion is as fast as passing the arrays through a simple analytical function and ~500 times faster than the slow Python loop (note by the number of calls that the program didn't even finish and it still used 657 seconds).

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
# Analytic (but wrong) approximation to the solution of the integral:
      108    1.850    0.017    2.583    0.024 DensityMap.py:473(space_sylinder)
# Slow python loop using scipy.integrate.quad:
       69   19.223    0.279  657.647    9.531 DensityMap.py:474(space_sylinder)
# Vectorized scipy.special.erf (Warren Weckesser's suggestion):
      108    1.786    0.017    2.517    0.023 DensityMap.py:475(space_sylinder)
```

Comment: Vectorization helps with specific operations you would like to perform on a list. When instead of a specific operation (e.g. multiplication) you are launching a sophisticated adaptive routine of numerical integration, this is not something where vectorization would help even in principle.  

The best thing to do would be to step back and re-think the ultimate purpose of computation. Are you trying to compute some double integral? Etc.

Comment: what you are looking for is probably to integrate vector valued functions... check the [Cubature algorithm](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature)

Comment: @SaulloCastro That looks like exactly what I was asking for, but Warren Weckesser's simple answer worked for the specific function I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral of `exp(-x*x)` is a scaled version of the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), so you can use [`scipy.special.erf`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erf.html) to compute the integral.  Given scalars `a` and `b`, the integral of your function from `a` to `b` is `0.5*np.sqrt(np.pi)*(erf(b) - erf(a))`.

`erf` is a ["ufunc"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.code-explanations.html#universal-functions), which means it handles array arguments.  Given `a_list` and `b_list`, your calculation can be written as

```
total = 0.5*np.sqrt(np.pi)*(erf(b_list) - erf(a_list)).sum()
```

The function `rho` can also be handled with `erf`, by using the appropriate scaling:

```
g = np.sqrt(2)*H
total = g*rho0*0.5*np.sqrt(np.pi)*(erf(b_list/g) - erf(a_list/g)).sum()
```

Check this against your slow solution before relying on it.  For some values, the subtraction of the `erf` functions can result in a significant loss of precision.

Comment: Thanks. This might be the solution. f is the function I am integrating, but it also contains some other factors which I omitted for simplisity in my explanation. I added the specific function in the question now. Can I easily implement this change in you answer? rho0 I could just add like this: 
total = np.sum(rho0 * 0.5*np.sqrt(np.pi)*(erf(b_list) - erf(a_list))) 
But what about the factor 1/(2*H^2)?

Comment: This is amazing! Just the kind of thing I was hoping for.