# Function integration returns “only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars”

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, typeerror, numerical-integration

I'm trying to integrate a function into a given range that shows the flow of particles in a zero-angle (theta) direction as a function of the energy E of the particles. I've tried several ways and got different errors but there are two that persist at the end. My knowledge of Python is limited, I try to learn new ways of doing stuff as I need them but I've been around this function for days with no success.

My function at the moment looks like this:

```
from numpy import radians, cos, arange
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integral(self):
    theta=0
    E = arange(1, 5000, 1)
    costh = cos(radians(theta))
    a = 18 / (E * costh + 145)
    b = (E + 2.7 / costh)**-2.7
    c = (E + 5) / (E + 5 / costh)
    return a*b*c*1**4


A = quad(integral, 500, 1000)
```

Applying "quad" to the function like this returns:

> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

If I don't put "self" as argument in the funtion, it returns:

> TypeError: integral() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Has someone an idea on how to bypass this?

Comment: `quad` takes a function that accepts one value, and returns one value.  It looks like your `intergral` doesn't do anything with the argument, and returns an array, values over 5000 points.  You may need to reread the `quad` docs and experiment with some of its examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`integral` must have one of the signatures described in the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad). In your case, a function taking a double as argument and returning a double seems appropriate.

`self` is only used for member functions of a class. It does not make sense outside a class definition. Replace that with a simple name, say `x` that will be the input argument of the function to integrate.

The function  must return a `double`. Since `E` is an array and you seem to make calculations with it, then the computed return value is likely to be an array too. It must be a scalar. Fix that and it will work. When you replace your function with something like:

```
def integral(x):
    return x * x
```

then it works. This is not what you need, of course, but this is the kind of arguments and return values that are required for `quad()` to work.

You may want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29035107/2311167) for an example on how `quad()` is being used.

Some recommendations:

- use four spaces for indentation (not 5 as in the example)
- parentheses around the result are not required. Remove for more clarity.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, it helped me a lot. I thought how could I get a scalar and came with a solution. E can be a function of theta, so I got around it by rearranging the funtion to only be dependent of theta. So I created a lambda funtion of theta with only that equation and with that the "quad" integration worked. It's not the same as the function above because in the case above I want to integrate between an energy range not an angular range, but once I got one I could get the other just by modifying the equation. Much appreciated!